# Como saber a linguagem do código e compilá-lo?

Tags: compilação

Gostaria de saber como faço para compilar esse código (e em que linguagem ele foi escrito)?

Achei ele em um [Fórum de Tibia](https://tibiaking.com/forums/topic/60567-auto-login) (Jogo) onde o objetivo é fazer um Login automático sempre que você abre o jogo.

Não faço ideia de como compilar um código, sou bem leigo no assunto.

Código:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Windows.h>
    #include <string>

    //Tibia 600 x 500 client default size
    //Enter Game = 80x,300y
    //OK button = 400, 350

    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    RECT rect;

    std::string login = "seulogin";
    std::string password = "suasenha";

    int main()
    {

    std::cout << "Searching Tibia..." << std::endl;
    HWND hwndTibia = NULL;
    while (hwndTibia == NULL)
    {
        hwndTibia = ::FindWindow(NULL, "Tibia");
    }   

    if (hwndTibia)
    {
        std::cout << "Tibia found." << std::endl;   
        GetClientRect(hwndTibia, &rect);
        width = rect.left - rect.right;
        height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
        std::cout << "Resolution : Width: " << width << " Height: " << height << std::endl;
        //click Enter Game
        SendMessage(hwndTibia, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(80, 300));
        Sleep(25);
        SendMessage(hwndTibia, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(80, 300));
        Sleep(100);     

        ////type login info, username/tab/password
        if (login.size() > 0 && password.size() > 0)
        {
            for (char& l : login)
            {
                SendMessage(hwndTibia, WM_CHAR, (int)l, NULL);
            }

            SendMessage(hwndTibia, WM_CHAR, 9, NULL);

            for (char& p : password)
            {
                SendMessage(hwndTibia, WM_CHAR, (int)p, NULL);
            }

        }

        ////click ok
        Sleep(50);
        SendMessage(hwndTibia, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(320, 345));
        Sleep(25);
        SendMessage(hwndTibia, WM_LBUTTONUP, MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(320, 345));     
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código está escrito em C++. Para compilar você pode utilizar o GCC, basta procurar como instalar essa ferramenta que você encontrará facilmente. (não se esqueça de adicionar o caminho do gcc nas variáveis de ambiente).
Assim que isso for feito, você pode compilar da seguinte maneira:

1. Abra o terminal e vá até o diretório onde o código se encontra.
2. Assim que estiver no diretório do código, basta digitar no terminal:
   g++ nomedoarquivo.cpp -o nomedoexecutavel
3. Pronto, o arquivo está compilado e será gerado um executável na mesma pasta.